# Store Procedure, Group multiple tables by time interval to new table: daily run schedule

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

Currently working on a thesis where I have been tasked with aggregating data to a new table

I'm trying to build out an aggregated table where I'll store each row group by date and a time interval (let's say 30 minutes).

I came across store procedures and think that this would be the best solution.

My source table is constructed as followed (StartDateTime = datetime2) (

```
StartDateTime           Name    ...   Path         
2021-02-28 20:23:43.1   Tom     ...   FG_T
2021-02-28 20:24:34.6   Tom     ...   LS_t
 ---                    ---     ...   ---
2021-02-28 20:35:09.5   Abby    ...   FS_t
2021-02-28 21:55:34.6   Tom     ...   FS_t
2021-XX-XX HH:MM:SS.s   Abby     ...  XX
```

My desire is to have an output table (must be a table I want to store it over time, not just temp) that counts the amount events that have happened within a given period, this procedure should be run once a day and create an entry for every available "timeslot" from the last 24h.

```
PeriodStart              Period(sek)    Name     Sum
2021-02-28 20:00:00.0    1800           Tom      2
2021-02-28 20:30:00.0    1800           Abby     1
2021-02-28 21:00:00.0    1800           NULL     NULL
2021-02-28 21:30:00.0    1800           Tom      1
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on where I could find information about creating something like this?

My thanks in advance from an aspiring SQL enthusiast :)

## Update 1:

As demonstrated within @SMor's answer, I'm seeking to use some sort of tally table to generate timeslots.

Once I looked at the code he provided, I realized that I had forgotten about a few constraints that I would like to address

Clarifying my desired outcome and structure of the current tables:

This task is meant to summarize several connections coming in via a given set of ports (trunks), the newly create table (the one formed within this process) shall later be used as a hooking point for a corresponding View that will be used within an SSRS.

My goal is to count the number of incoming connections within a given timeslot per trunk (hence group by trunk as well).
Once I get this first part in place, it would also be much desired to see the max amount of connections at the same time within a given slot. (Such as MaxConnectionAtOnce )

Table: RAW_DATA

| GatewayName | StartDateTime | DisconnectDateTime | ConnectionDuration | Trunk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GW1 | 2021-02-24 20:20:43.1 | 2021-02-24 20:22:32.9 | 52964 | T1 |
| GW1 | 2021-02-24 20:21:23.6 | 2021-02-24 20:21:55.1 | 51036 | T1 |
| GW1 | 2021-02-24 20:26:50.0 | 2021-02-24 20:28:24.0 | 9490 | T1 |
| GW2 | 2021-02-24 20:41:49.0 | 2021-02-24 20:43:24.0 | 9490 | T2 |
| GW3 | 2021-02-24 22:46:54.2 | 2021-02-24 22:48:25.2 | 9087 | T1 |
| GW99 | 2021-02-24 22:47:25.1 | 2021-02-24 22:47:54.4 | 2917 | T2 |

I tried to add it into a store procedure, I have added block comments ( /* */ ) around the modifications I did.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [schemma].[TrunkSummery]
@date datetime2(7),
@period int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Creat timeslotable
        with numbers(val) as 
            (select 1 union all select val + 1 from numbers where val < 48)
        select @date, nbr.val, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val - 1) * 30, @date) as period_start, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val    ) * 30, @date) as period_end 
        from numbers as nbr 
        order by nbr.val;

        with numbers(val) as 
            (select 1 union all select val + 1 from numbers where val < 48),
        periods as (
            select @date as [date], nbr.val, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val - 1) * 30, @date) as period_start, 
           dateadd(minute, (nbr.val    ) * 30, @date) as period_end 
           from numbers as nbr)
        select pers.period_start, @period as Period, src.trunk, count(src.trunk) as 'all' 
        /*, count(maxAtOnce) */ 
        --from periods as pers left  join @raw_data as src 
        from periods as pers inner join HDO.RAW_DATA as src 
        on src.StartDateTime >= pers.period_start and src.StartDateTime < pers.period_end
        group by src.trunk, pers.period_start, pers.period_end
        order by pers.period_start, src.trunk,  pers.period_end
END
GO

EXECUTE [schemma].[TrunkSummery] @date = '20210224', @period = 30;
GO
```

Based on my attempts I think that I somehow need group/order on the trunks as well.

```
--Current output
period_start                 Period   trunk     all
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0000000  30       T1        3
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0000000  30       T1        1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0000000  30       T2        1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0000000  30       T1        1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0000000  30       T2        1


-- Desired
period_start                 Period   trunk     all    max
2021-02-24 20:00:00.0000000  30       T1        3      2
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0000000  30       T1        1      1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0000000  30       T1        1      1
2021-02-24 20:30:00.0000000  30       T2        1      1
2021-02-24 22:30:00.0000000  30       T2        1      1
```

Is this fusible?

[Fiddle based on @SMor with new table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4887c8c40442d8501d688886d61ca519)

Comment: It would help if you add a create table and insert statements to your question. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is it safe to assume your time range will always start and end at midnight? So if you want a half hour interval, the first interval is 2/28 at 12AM to 12:30AM, and the last interval will be from 11:30 PM to midnight?

Comment: @McNets, I can understand this argument. Will look into adding some additional information. I do usually provide more details of what tests I’ll done so far, however my intention with this post was to figure out more resources that  I could read up on. Im not sure what a table structure like this is called. Hence I was not able to elaborate in a better fashion.

Comment: @J.D. I assume for now that would be the case yes, however it could be that a time-slot has 0 events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) (also called a numbers table) to start. These have many uses and can easily be used to generate intervals like you need.

The idea is to generate a sequence of number corresponding to the intervals in a day. You can cross join that against a table of dates to get the complete set of intervals for all the dates of concern to get every possible interval.

With that resultset, you can then join to your source data and aggregate as you typically do. You can inner join if you only want the intervals that exist in your source data or you can outer join to get all intervals. Note that I use the lazy way of generating the numbers (recursive cte) - but the list is very small for this requirement. I also only considered a single date which was set in a local variable `@date`. Therefore that skips the need for a cross join against your set of dates.

```
with numbers(val) as 
    (select 1 union all select val + 1 from numbers where val < 48),
periods as (
    select @date as [date], nbr.val, 
   dateadd(minute, (nbr.val - 1) * 30, @date) as period_start, 
   dateadd(minute, (nbr.val    ) * 30, @date) as period_end 
   from numbers as nbr)
select pers.period_start, pers.period_end, src.name, count(src.name) as cnt 
--from periods as pers left  join @source as src 
from periods as pers inner join @source as src 
on src.startdt >= pers.period_start and src.startdt < pers.period_end
group by pers.period_start, pers.period_end, src.name
order by pers.period_start, pers.period_end, src.name
```

I leave you a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2317a4cde767c794026020d57c7740da) to demonstrate.

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks @SMor. I will have a test run og this tonight. Will report back with confirmation  once im up and running.

Comment: I did add a section to the main question, do you mind taking a look at it to see if you can help me in the right direction once more. Truly appreciate what you have done so far!